# How to find the count of particular object in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like below:

```
const arr_obj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        children: [],
        type: 'TYPE1',
    },
    {
         id: '2',
         children: [
             {
                  id: '1',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '2',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '3',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
         ]
         type: 'TYPE2',
     },
     {
         id: '3',
         children: [
             {
                  id: '4',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '5',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '6',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
         ]
         type: 'TYPE2',
     }
 ]
```

I have to find out the count of type: '`MAIN`'. these '`MAIN`' will be within type: "`type2`"

So the expected count is 6. The outer children array can be empty and sometimes inner children array with type: "`type2`" is not there at all examples like below:

```
children: [] //empty array


children: [
    {
        id: '1',
        children: [],
        type: 'TYPE1',
    },
] //no children with type: 'TYPE2'
```

Could someone help me with this? New to programming.

EDIT:

what i have tried?

```
const findAllChildrenOfType = (obj, type) => {
    let count = 0;
    if (obj.type === type) count++;
    if (obj.children) {
        obj.children.forEach(child => {
            const childCount = findAllChildrenOfType(child, 
            "MAIN");
            count += childCount;
        })
    }
    return count;
}

findAllChildrenOfType(arr_obj, "TYPE2");
```

But this gives me count always 0.

Comment: Can you please share what have you tried till now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of use it with all object i use `forEach` and use function for each object like:

```js
const arr_obj = [{
    id: '1',
    children: [],
    type: 'TYPE1',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    children: [{
        id: '1',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
    ],
    type: 'TYPE2',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    children: [{
        id: '4',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        children: [{
          //some attributes
        }],
        type: 'MAIN',
      },
    ],
    type: 'TYPE2'
  }
];

const findAllChildrenOfType = (obj, type) => {
  let count = 0;  
  if (obj.type === type) {
    if (type === 'MAIN') count++;
    if (obj.children) {
      obj.children.forEach(child => {
        const childCount = findAllChildrenOfType(child,
          "MAIN");
        count += childCount;
      })
    }
  }
  return count;
}
let countAll = 0;
arr_obj.forEach(el => {
  countAll += findAllChildrenOfType(el, "TYPE2");
});
console.log(countAll)
```

Comment: thanks but i was expecting the output to be 6. in here it gives 8

Comment: I see 6 `MAIN` and 2 `TYPE 2`, I can not see well?

Comment: nope i mean i need to get the count of only type MAIN within TYPE2. Thanks

Comment: There are three objects, two of them have type 2, inside each of these there are three MAIN

Comment: yes so i want to get the count of MAIN types only. so 6 intotal

Comment: ok, i change code see update.

Answer (score 1):

A small recursive loop.

```js
const data=[{id:"1",children:[],type:"TYPE1"},{id:"2",children:[{id:"1",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"2",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"3",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"}],type:"TYPE2"},{id:"3",children:[{id:"4",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"5",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"6",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"}],type:"TYPE2"}];
const data2=[{id:"1",children:[],type:"TYPE1"},{id:"2",children:[{id:"1",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"2",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"3",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"}],type:"TYPE2"},{id:"3",children:[{id:"4",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"5",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"6",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"7",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"8",children:[{}],type:"MAIN2"}],type:"TYPE2"}];

function find(arr) {

  let count = 0;

  function loop(arr) {
    for (const obj of arr) {
      const { type, children } = obj;
      if (type === 'TYPE2') loop(children);
      if (type === 'MAIN') ++count;
    }
  }

  loop(arr);
  
  return count;

}

console.log(find(data));
console.log(find(data2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr_obj = [
    {
        id: '1',
        children: [],
        type: 'TYPE1',
    },
    {
         id: '2',
         children: [
             {
                  id: '1',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '2',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '3',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
         ],
         type: 'TYPE2',
     },
     {
         id: '3',
         children: [
             {
                  id: '4',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '5',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
             {
                  id: '6',
                  children: [
                      {
                          //some attributes
                       }
                  ],
                  type: 'MAIN',
             },
         ],
         type: 'TYPE2',
     }
 ];

let count = 0

const findAllChildrenOfType = (obj, type) => {
  if (obj?.type === type) count++;
  if(obj?.children?.length) {
    obj.children.forEach((child) => {
       findAllChildrenOfType(child, type);      
    });
  }
//   return count;
};

arr_obj.forEach((child) => {
    if(child.type === 'TYPE2') {
        findAllChildrenOfType(child, "MAIN");
    }
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a small function inside your `findAllChildrenOfType()` function, that will iterate over the array, and increment the count if it encounters an object with given `type`. Then you can return the `count` from the parent function, by subtracting the number of objects with initial `type` (*"TYPE2"* in this case), since they also get added up, when you increment the count in `if(obj.type === type)`.

```js
const arr_obj=[{id:"1",children:[],type:"TYPE1"},{id:"2",children:[{id:"1",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"2",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"3",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"}],type:"TYPE2"},{id:"3",children:[{id:"4",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"5",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"},{id:"6",children:[{}],type:"MAIN"}],type:"TYPE2"}];

const findAllChildrenOfType = (arr_obj, type) => {
  let count = 0;
  let findElem = (arr_obj, type) => {
    arr_obj.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.type === type) {
        count++;
        if (obj.children.length) {
          return findElem(obj.children, "MAIN");
        } 
      }
    });
    return count;
  }
  count = findElem(arr_obj, type);
  let fil = arr_obj.filter(obj => obj.type === type).length;
  return count - fil;
}

console.log(findAllChildrenOfType(arr_obj, "TYPE2"));
```

Comment: Hey, Can you please take a look? @stackuser